# converting entry widget string to integer in tcl/tk

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, tkinter-entry

I want to be able to enter a number into an entry widget in tcl/tk and be able to multiply this number by 1000. The problem is when I do this I always get 0. I'm assuming this number is a string and needs to be converted somehow.

Can anyone tell me how to do this please?

Comment: You assume incorrectly. So the problem must be somewhere else. Maybe you show the result of a calculation that was already done before the number was entered. It's impossible to tell based on the provided information. Please show your code.

Comment: In Tcl, everything you see at the script level is a string and commands like expr know how to handle any needed conversions. I you would like us to help you with your code, please show it to us.

Answer (score 2):

In tcl/tk a variable can be interpreted both as a string and a number, depending on the context. This is checked in the background. For example:

```
set x 10
append x 0
set y [expr $x+10]
```

x is interpreted as a string first and as an integer next.
If you want to access the value of a entry you can use the -textvariable option:

```
entry .e -textvariable ::v
pack .e
```

v must be a global variable. It equals the value in the entry.
If you write:

```
set ::v 10
```

the display in the entry widget will also change. In your case, you can write:

```
set y [expr 1000*$v]
```